# How to derive the FIRST equation from the SECOND one?

Tags: aggregate-demand

[image]First equation  **[image: strong text]**  Dynamic Aggregate Demand

How  the derive from second equation the first one?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend multiplying first eq by the only nominator in eq, then performing additions and subtractions.

These operations are reversible.